# MapView goes back to the original position when I try to zoom in or zoom out, it keeps fixated on the user location

Tags: swiftui, core-location, swiftui-list, apple-maps, mapview

I could get the user location and even track it but when user moves the view updates and follows the user. The problem is when I try to zoom in or out it goes back to the original position. This happens both time when the user is moving and when the user keep still. I'm trying to code it in SwiftUI.

I would like to freely roam the map after getting the user location even if user is moving.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Highlight exactly where you struggle. Pleae take the [tour] and try to post a [mre].